# How to configure a list of API requests per screen in React Native

Tags: android, node.js, react-native, mobile

At this point I am not very sure if what I want to do is recommended or if it even has a pattern name.

I currently have a mobile app as a frontend. It shows a card feed that can be configured from the backend. I can say which cards to show, which information, etc.

Right now, the issue is that I load them all at once. For those familiar with React Native, I use a ScrollView which automatically renders all the cards/requests at once.

I would like to improve this, by having one single requests per page, and the response should return the list of API requests that actually load the information.

Like a first API request that brings the configuration of the screen, and then using a ListView to show each requests. The difference is that every request should be actually loaded when they appear on screen. Also, I could support pagination.

Is there any framework that could help? Best practices?

Thanks

PS. I understand this could be opinion based but I am trying to understand if this already has a patter name or framework that could do this for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Having an API request that fires on each screen, solely to tell the screen which other API requests to make, is quite inefficient. It sounds like you want an infinite scroll view with pagination on the API side, so you can load a sensible amount of records each time, and then as the user scrolls, load in more below.

There is a good RN package at https://github.com/expo/react-native-infinite-scroll-view for this - the docs are pretty good, but basically the key props are `canLoadMore`, which tells the scroll view whether it should try to load more content or if it's at the end, and `onLoadMoreAsync`, where you can provide an async function to fetch the next page of records.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Good point. The thing is that, let's say you have 3 cards and one of them takes longer to load, I want that card to not affect the rest of the cards. If I have one request, you are blocking the rest.

Comment: I see, and is each card it's own scrollview too? Is it like a tab structure on a single screen? Sounds like they should indeed be separate requests, but I'd be tempted to load the first page of the first card, and then fire off the first page for the other cards once that's loaded, so that by the time the user navigates to them, that initial content is already loaded, and the rest loads on demand via additional pages.

Comment: I just spotted the bit above too where you said that the cards themselves are configurable from the backend, so in that case it does sound like you'd need an additional request to inform the app what cards are available - you could include the first page of results for the default card in that request as well, so it's still just one request initially. Alternatively, if the card configuration doesn't change that often, that might be something you load in the background on app startup only perhaps.

Comment: There are not scrollviews because that would make a lot of issues. They have fixed height. Imagine the Facebook feed where there are many different "cards" like status, images, videos, etc. Now, imagine one of them just takes a lot of time to actually render/load information. I want to lazy load that card. Since the config will come from the backend, I need to send to the app a list of cards configurations to load, because each card will have one api to fetch. Makes more sense that way?

Comment: Ah OK, sure. So in that case, I presume if they have a lot of data to show, you're only showing a few on screen at a time, making the initial page of data quite small? Can you not get away with one early request to load 3-4 cards, and optimize that call so it's as fast as possible, and then lazy load additional cards in individually if you need to as the entire screen is scrolled?

Comment: Yep, what you just said is what I want to do. I was just asking if this is recommended or if it is another pattern. Basically, I would be loading the first page of cards and then making an infinitive scroll of cards. The thing is that I have a wrapper on my cards that make the loading for me, so basically I would load a list of loaders, if that makes sense. If you have a moment to give your thoughts about it, that would be great, just to confirm I am not doing something too crazy.

Comment: Yep it sounds like you're on the right path - I think if you can find a way to include an initial default dataset in that first call ("load a list of loaders"), just to avoid needing two calls (list of cards, first card) before showing any data, it'll be a better user experience. The rest as you say you can load on demand. What's the backend built in? It's worth looking at performance profiling that too to make sure those initial calls are as performant and fast as possible - my web expertise is with Ruby on Rails, so if you're using that I can give you some pointers there too.